# Change button color inside the foreach

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, codeigniter, button, foreach

I can not change the colors of buttons. 
Only shows green. See the image.
I want each status has a color. buttons in different colors
How do I change within the foreach ?

[image: Look at the image]

```
   <?php
                    $query = $this->sindico->get_listfinanceiro()->result();
                    foreach ($query as $linha):
                        echo '<tr>';
                        printf('<td>%s / %s</td>', ($linha->numero_apart) ? :'/', ($linha->nome_usu));
                        printf('<td>%s</td>', $linha->data_pagamento);
                        printf('<td>%s</td>', "Bs:".$linha->valor_pagamento);

                        if (!isset($linha->valor_pagamento["PAGO"])):
                        printf('<td><button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-xs">%s</button></td>', $linha->status_pagamento);

                        elseif (!isset($linha->valor_pagamento["PENDENTE"])):
                            printf('<td><button type="button" class="btn btn-warning btn-xs">%s</button></td>', $linha->status_pagamento);

                        elseif (!isset($linha->valor_pagamento['NO PAGO'])):
                            printf('<td><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs">%s</button></td>', $linha->status_pagamento);
                        endif;
                        printf('<td class="text-center">%s</td>', '<div class="btn-group btn-xs"><button data-toggle="dropdown" class="btn btn-xs dropdown-toggle"  data-original-title="" title="">Action<span class="caret"></span></button><ul class="dropdown-menu pull-right"><li><a href="editar/'.$linha->id_finan.'">Edit</a></li><li><a href="excluir/'.$linha->id_finan.'">Delete</a></li>' );
                        echo '</tr>';
                    endforeach;
                    ?>
```

Comment: Have you tried var_dump($linha->valor_pagamento) and checked what you're getting?

Comment: problem is not in the data. the problem is in the if and elseif

Comment: It's probably satisfying the first condition every time, and therefore not checking other else if conditions. Try using multiple if's instead of else if.

Answer (score 0):

> Try this

```
<?php
                $query = $this->sindico->get_listfinanceiro()->result();
                $btn_color_class ="";
                foreach ($query as $linha):
                    echo '<tr>';
                    printf('<td>%s / %s</td>', ($linha->numero_apart) ? :'/', ($linha->nome_usu));
                    printf('<td>%s</td>', $linha->data_pagamento);
                    printf('<td>%s</td>', "Bs:".$linha->valor_pagamento);

                    if (!isset($linha->valor_pagamento["PAGO"])):
                    $btn_color_class = "btn-success";
                    printf('<td><button type="button" class="btn '.$btn_color_class.' btn-xs">%s</button></td>', $linha->status_pagamento);

                    if (!isset($linha->valor_pagamento["PENDENTE"])):
                        $btn_color_class = "btn-warning";
                        printf('<td><button type="button" class="btn '.$btn_color_class.' btn-xs">%s</button></td>', $linha->status_pagamento);

                    if (!isset($linha->valor_pagamento['NO PAGO'])):
                    $btn_color_class = "btn-danger";
                        printf('<td><button type="button" class="btn '.$btn_color_class.' btn-xs">%s</button></td>', $linha->status_pagamento);
                    endif;
                    printf('<td class="text-center">%s</td>', '<div class="btn-group btn-xs"><button data-toggle="dropdown" class="btn btn-xs dropdown-toggle"  data-original-title="" title="">Action<span class="caret"></span></button><ul class="dropdown-menu pull-right"><li><a href="editar/'.$linha->id_finan.'">Edit</a></li><li><a href="excluir/'.$linha->id_finan.'">Delete</a></li>' );
                    echo '</tr>';
                endforeach;
                ?>
```

Comment: came this message Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'endforeach' (T_ENDFOREACH)